# Drupal Contextual Links Not showing on home page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

i have a website and want to give a user limited access but give them the ability to edit all blocks on each page, i have the main navigation and side navigation just sitting in a block but i cant get the cod wheel to show up when that user hovers over.

In the permissions i have Use Contextual Links check but it doesnt seem to be working still.

How do i get around this? am i not checking a certain box in the permissions area? if so which ones should i check?

Thanks heaps guys

Answer (score 2):

Dou you use Theme Developer module? It requires Devel. Disable that module and reload. Also try to flush the caches.

I realise it's been over a year and a half, but I just had this problem and found your post while looking for a solution.

Comment: This helped me. Did not realize that Devel messes with contextual links.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the permission "**Use contextual links**".

Just go to **admin/people/permissions#module-contextual**.

Hope this works... Muhammad.

Comment: Hello  Muhammad i have that checked already and it still doesnt work, im assuming there is another one i have to check.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

```
<?php if ($action_links): ?><ul class="action-links"><?php print render($action_links); ?></ul><?php endif; ?>
```

in your page.tpl.php